# How to read and write coordinateMatrix to a file in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I had a very sparse dataframe in pyspark, I converted this dataframe into CoordinatedMatrix. Now I want to save this matrix on hdfs to reuse it later as for training my model. Unfortunately, I did not find any solution for this. Any advice?

example:

```
>> mat.entries.collect()
[MatrixEntry(1, 0, 1.0), MatrixEntry(1, 1, 1.0), MatrixEntry(1, 2, 2.0),MatrixEntry(1, 3, 1.0), MatrixEntry(2, 0, 2.0), MatrixEntry(2, 1, 1.0), MatrixEntry(2, 2, 3.0), MatrixEntry(2, 3, 5.0)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no recommended format here and `CoordinateMatrix` has very simple structure so you can choose pretty much anything, for example Parquet:

```
mat.entries.toDF().write.parquet(path)
```

and later read:

```
CoordinateMatrix(spark.read.parquet(path).rdd.map(lambda row: MatrixEntry(*row)))
```